# Where should shiro.ini go in a web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, shiro

Does anybody know where shiro.ini is supposed to be placed within a Java web application?  Is it the WEB-INF or perhaps META-INF directory?

Comment: Never heard of shiro.ini before.  Is it part of some framework?

Comment: @Taylor It's a configuration file you can use for the Shiro security framework.

Answer (score 5):

From the [configuation doc](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html)

> Resources can be acquired from the file system, classpath, or URLs when prefixed with file:, classpath:, or url: respectively.

Here is an example of how to create a SecurityManager from the classpath:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = 
             new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
```

For typical usage `shiro.ini` is placed on the classpath. In this case you can use `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: In development, if you are using a build tool like Maven, you can put it in a resources source folder.